# Using animations in android

Tags: android, animation, panel, sliding

I am making an android application that needs to display a sliding animation as seen on the Samsung Omnia, this will bring up a linearlayout once it is visible(When the user drags the linearlayout out). I am getting an error at the final TransparentPanel that says that it cannot be resolved to a type. I am not familiar with this, so how can i fix it??? Please help and thanks SO much in advance! I am using this code to do so:

```
public class Animation extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
CheckBox c1,c2,c3;
int key=0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testanimation);

    final TransparentPanel popup = (TransparentPanel) findViewById(R.id.popup_window);
    popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.show_popup_button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(key==0){
                key=1;
                popup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slid3_n);
            }
            else if(key==1){
                key=0;
                popup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.slid4_n);
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It can't resolve to a type because `TransparentPanel` is not a class defined in the Android SDK.  Have you created a `TransparentPanel` class?

Comment: It crossed my mine that it may have been a missing activity, but i was using a tutorial to do this, which i dont think contained that class, but i'll search i bit more and try to find the activity that i need